# Multiple lines of input for multiple variables

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I would like to enter multiple lines of values for 3 different variables.

For example, lets say I have `$a`, `$b`, and `$c` in a line like:

```
ADD $a in $b to get $C
```

My input will be in rows for all 3 variables :

I know how to do for just a variable but I'm stuck for more than that:

```
cat > a_list;for a in `cat a_list`; do  echo "ADD \""$a"\";"; done
```

My example output should be as below:

```
ADD apple in duck to get 11    
ADD orange in cat to get 22    
ADD pineapple in dog to get 33    
ADD xx in bb to get 44   
ADD abc in def to get 55
```

My input would be as below:

```
apple
orange
pineapple
xx
abc


duck    
cat    
dog   
bb    
def


11    
22    
33    
44    
55
```

Is this doable? or are there other ways to achieve the output?

Comment: You question is not clear as it stands. Which language is it for? Bash? Which variable should hold which value at the end?

Comment: Its Unix terminal command. The example that I gave is for variable `$a` which means my output would have been something like below:

`ADD apple  <br/>


ADD orange  <br/>


ADD pineapple  <br/>


ADD xx  <br/>


ADD abc`  <br/>

Comment: So that's probably bash. Try to execute `echo $0` in the terminal and tell us what it prints.

Comment: I am getting `bash`

Comment: What does the for loop you give in your post print? Does `for l in \`cat a_list\`; do  echo "ADD \"$a\" in \"$b\" to get \"$c\";"; done` do what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry it should've been `for a in `cat a_list`;`.
And nope it doesn't. Because i want to give three different input for three different variables.The above data of "apple, orange.." is just for variable"a".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you would like to see. Also, clarify whether you actually have blank lines in your input file, and what you want us to do with each line. Should we combine each set of three lines? If so, why do you have 5 (or 9 if we count the blank ones) lines in your input?

Comment: @terdon I have just edited the question. Sorry, I'm a noob here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but i) are the blank lines part of your input file? ii) How can we identify the "groups"? Are the separated by two empty lines instead of one? You need to make sure the input you show is is _exactly_ like the real input you have. iii) should the output also have the blank lines you show?

Comment: Okay i have edited again, both input and output.

In my input there are only two blank lines between groups. These two blank lines are the one differentiating the groups. Each group in the input is for one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v RS= -F '\n' '
  {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) a[NR,i] = $i}
  NF > max {max = NF}
  NR == 3 {exit}
  END{
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
      printf "ADD %s in %s to get %s\n", a[1,i], a[2,i], a[3,i]
  }' < input
```

With `RS=`, that's the *paragraph mode*, where records are paragraphs. `perl` has a similar feature with the `-00` option (not to be confused with `-0`). We use newline as a field separator, so each field is a line of that paragraph. You can leave off the `-F '\n'` is you'd rather fields be each *word* of those paragraphs.

If you want the strings to get generated by a shell expanding `ADD $a in $b to get $c`, then you could still have `awk` put them in a more useful order and post-process that with the shell:

```
< input awk -v RS= -F '\n' '
  {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) a[NR,i] = $i}
  NF > max {max = NF}
  NR == 3 {exit}
  END{
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) for (j = 1; j <= NR; j++)
      print a[j,i]
  }' |
  while 
    IFS= read -r a &&
    IFS= read -r b &&
    IFS= read -r c
  do
    printf '%s\n' "ADD $a in $b to get $c"
  done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first code helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now we can go for an answer:

```
# first create a file where the groups are delimited by one empty line
sed '/^$/ { N; s/^\n$//; }' < input_file > temp_file_1
# split the file into three files one for $a, one for $b and one for $c
sed -n '0,/^$/p' temp_file_1 | sed '$d' > a_values
sed -n '/^$/,/^$/p' temp_file_1 | sed '1d;$d' > b_values
sed '1,/^$/d' temp_file_1 | sed '1,/^$/d' > c_values
# paste the three files together and read them into the variables $a, $b, $c line by line
paste a_values b_values c_values | while read a b c; do
  echo "ADD $a in $b to get $c"
done
```

Comment: Your `sed '/^$/ { s/^\n$//; }'` has no effect, `\n` will never be present in the pattern space. Use `awk`'s paragraph mode (with an empty RS) to select paragraphs

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks I missed the `N` which I used locally. But now I learned something about awk and even understand your awk script above.

Comment: Note that `sed '/^$/ { N; s/^\n$//; }'` only works if there are only 2 blank lines between the paragraphs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: wasn't that the specification by the OP?